# Making a list of Strings from the SymbolNames for a list of Graphics

Tags: graphics, export, evaluation, hold

Having generated a list of plots, such as

```
plot01 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}];
plot02 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 6}];
plotList =  {plot01, plot02}
```

Then create strings with the name of each plot. 
The following works for the individual plot names

```
plot01Name = ToString[HoldForm[plot01]] 
plot01Name // FullForm 
(* "plot01" *)
```

but mapping this to the list doesn't work

```
plotListNames = Map[ToString[HoldForm[#]] &, plotList ];
plotListNames // FullForm
(* List["-Graphics-", "-Graphics-"] *)
```

Looking for an efficient way to create the list of plot names, so that the names can be used to Export the plots.  The name of the exported plot should be similar to the name of the symbol chosen for the plot.

### Update

From the comments by @b3m2a1, the following produces the desired result.

```
plot01 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}];
plot02 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 6}];
plotListHold =  Thread@HoldForm[{plot01, plot02}];
Export[ ToString[#] ~~ ".jpg", ReleaseHold[#] ] & /@ plotListHold
GraphicsRow[ReleaseHold[plotListHold]]
```

Comment: You need `plotList = Thread@HoldForm[{plot01, plot02}]` then `Map[ToString, plotList]` will work

Comment: Thanks! that gives a list of Strings, which can be used in Export. And then to use the plotList to display the plots (not for Export), something like this? GraphicsRow[ReleaseHold[plotList]]

Answer (score 2):

Cross posted from https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1984979

I would take a different approach. HoldForm is difficult to control and it can have strange side effects. I would use notebook programming to grab the input cell and manipulate it. I think it will be more reliable:

First, define a function that will take an input string and parse it, and save the file using the filename. For example, "p1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 6}]" gets saved by making a jpg from p1 and calling the file "Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 6}].jpg"

```
saveFile[x_] := 
 Module[{lst}, lst = StringSplit[x, "="]; 
  Export[lst[[2]] <> ".jpg", ToExpression[lst[[1]]], "jpg"]]
```

Next, make a function to grab the previous input line and send it to saveFile[]: (Note that most of the code below is so that the result is inserted after the existing cell. It makes for a cleaner notebook. If you do not care, many of the lines in this function go away and the save is inserted before the plot)

```
saveIt2[] := 
 Module[{nb = InputNotebook[], currentCell}, 
  SelectionMove[nb, Previous, CellContents, 3]; (*  go back to the previous input cell *); 
  currentCell = NotebookRead[nb];  (* save the cell *);
  SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell, 2];   (*  move back down selecting my cell *); 
  SelectionMove[nb, After, Cell];   (* move after my cell *); 
  NotebookWrite[nb, currentCell];  (*   insert the contents of the saved cell *); 
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Cell];   (* select the inserted cell *); 
  NotebookApply[nb, 
   "saveFile[ToString[\"\[SelectionPlaceholder]\"]]"];   (*  insert the save function *);
  SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[nb] (*  evaluate the new cell and save the file *) ]
```

To use the code:

```
p1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 6}]
saveIt2[]
```

This will go and create a new cell with the save function and export the plot. I suppose an upgrade would be to create a function or button that deletes all the saveFile cells when complete so you can reevaluate the notebook without side effects.